# How to init EnumMap which uses another map as value

Tags: java, collections, thread-safety, multimap, enum-map

```
private static EnumMap<Edition, ListMultimap<KeyClass, ValueClass>> 
   valueByKeyPerEdition = Collections.synchronizedMap(
     new EnumMap<Edition, ListMultimap<KeyClass, KeyClass>>());
```

I want to init a thread-safe map of map. Firstly, I tried the init function above, but it says `no suitable constructor found for EnumMap`. And then I tried to add `Edition.class`, result in `new EnumMap<Edition, ListMultimap<KeyClass, KeyClass>>());`
, it still doesn't work. Error message is `incompatible                                                                                                                                                              types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) K,V exist so that Map<K,V> conforms to EnumMap<Edition, ListMultimap<KeyClass, ValueClass>>`.

Could anyone help? Thanks in advance! I know the basic of Generic, but really confuse about how `valueByKeyPerEdition` should be initilized.

Comment: Try `private static Map<Edition, ListMultimap<KeyClass, ValueClass>> valueByKeyPerEdition = Collections.synchronizedMap(new EnumMap<>(Edition.class));`

Comment: FYI, the inner map is still not synchronized unless you wrap it in `Multimaps.synchronizedListMultimap()`.

Comment: @shmosel why does it need to be changed as `private static Map<Edition, ListMultimap` instead of keeping using EnumMap?

Comment: Because it's *not* an EnumMap. It's another Map implementation that delegates to your EnumMap.

Comment: @shmosel I see. If it's not a EnumMap, would it be a problem if I use the enum class `Edition` as its key?

Comment: Not at all. EnumMap is just a specific implementation of the generic Map interface, which accepts any type as a key.

Comment: @shmosel Yep! You are right. Thanks for your help! If you want to write a answer for it, I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Collections.synchronizedMap()` returns a different `Map` implementation that delegates to its argument, so you need to change the field type to `Map` instead of `EnumMap`:

```
private static Map<Edition, ListMultimap<KeyClass, ValueClass>> valueByKeyPerEdition =
        Collections.synchronizedMap(new EnumMap<>(Edition.class));
```

Note that synchronizing the outer map doesn't ensure the thread-safety of its contents.